# How to calculate VaR on loss distribution

Tags: probability, default-probability

I sorted simulated portfolio losses in ascending order (sorted_losses variable). X-axis is loss, Y-axis probability of loss. I want to calculate 95% Value at risk in R.
I used the below code, but am I choosing the correct side of distribution, because VaR value is lower than the mean?

```
confidence_level <- 0.95
var_95 <- quantile(sorted_losses, 1 - confidence_level)
cat("Value at Risk (VaR) at 95% confidence level:", var_95, "\n")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Is the only available data on losses? Because usually a loss distribution consists of both profit and losses, where losses are to the right and profits are to the left (as you have shown above). But back to the question, VaR should be higher than the mean (and to the right of your distribution) loss amount because your distribution looks like all losses.

Comment: I just checked the quantile function in R and I think you can use: var_95 <- quantile(sorted_losses, confidence_level) instead.

Comment: @Kai Hi! yes, I only have loss data and the idea is to find a value of loss that could be exceeded at 5% probability. Should I change confidence level to 0,05 and get the right side of the distribution, or maybe there is a better way?

Comment: @Kai thank you, that seems to work.

Comment: Actually, using 0.95 as the second argument in quantile() gets the right side of the distribution already.

Comment: Just saw your recent comment, no worries! You can give me an upvote if you feel my answers have helped you :)

Comment: This is a very odd distribution. You are suggesting this is only loss data, and no profits. It seems to be a normal distribution centred about a loss of 1.5mm. WIth essentially no probability or any occurences of losses close to zero.  If you simulated a portfoilio it would traditionally be centered at zero (so profits and losses). If you took just the losses it would be a half-normal distribution. Do you understand what I am indicating?

Comment: @Attack68 I know it's not the usual VaR. But I did the Monte Carlo simulation defined that if the random generator draws a number higher than the default probability of a loan it continues to perform. However, if the number drawn is lower, the loan is assumed to have defaulted. Then I assign a dummy variable to each loan (1-defaults, 0-doesnt) and aggregate the total loss which is shown here.